# Why Can't I Use a "New" Expression As a Statement in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax

Why can't I start a line using a parenthesis followed by the keyword new?? For example:

```
(New <custom_obj>).foo(var)
```

In that case is obvious that I'm trying to avoid creating a named instance of the the <custom_obj> because I know that I'll only be using it at that sentence.

Note that actually creating a named instance is not a problem for me... I just wanna know the reason why this is not possible.

Comment: I would advise using static methods instead of kudging things like this to save memory

Comment: I was in this context: (New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)).Fill(table). As you can see; I cannot create static methods there unless I inherit OleDBDataAdapter... and for that I would definitely create the named instance with no hesitation.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you expect as answer, VB.NET just doesn't support it, they might add it later.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't it? Is there any documentation, perhaps in MSDN, about it? The thing is that (New <custom_obj>) should return a custom_obj instance by default... it almost seems as if MS wants to explicitly avoid that syntax.

Comment: Skip the code obfuscation and write things on multiple lines, with static methods if necessary. You, me, *and* the compiler will be happier.

Comment: I'm with Cody Gray. Furthermore isn't OleDbAdapter disposable, which means this shorthand doesn't dispose it. Longer version with Using would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want a language lawyer answer? Look in the VB.NET Language Specification, beginning at [10. Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711981.aspx). The simplest answer is that the word “Expression” does not appear on that page. NewExpression is explicitly distinct from InvocationExpression, so you can use an InvocationExpression in an InvocationStatement, but you can only use a NewExpression in a LocalDeclarationStatement or in the context of some greater expression.

More handwavingly, the VB.NET syntax is designed to be easy to read, write and parse, and one way it accomplishes this is by being careful about what’s a Statement and what’s an Expression. Python is similar — an assignment is a statement and *not* an expression. There’s no reason for every language to be exactly like C.

*But*, as chibacity points out, you can work around this with the `Call` statement:

```
call new object.toString
```

will compile successfully. Try to make your classes meaningful, instead.

Comment: +1 C# special cases and treats the 'new...' expression as a statement - vb does not. You can however turn it into a statement as follows 'Call new object().ToString()'.